# Facebook IOS sdk calling synchronous

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to call the facebook sdk synchronously. I know that this is not recommended, but this is just one part of a bigger initialization which is already running on a separate thread while the main thread is displaying a "please wait" screen.
I have tried the following code:

```
    NSConditionLock *threadLock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition:101];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Completionhandler called");
         [threadLock lock];
         [threadLock unlockWithCondition:100];
     }];
    NSLog(@"Waiting for unlock");
    [threadLock lockWhenCondition:100];
    [threadLock unlock];
    NSLog(@"Unlocked");
```

This method of locking works in other scenarios, for example when running threads via dispatch_async. However, in the above code, the completionhandler is never being called, and the lock is therefore never released. If I out comment all the threadlock lines, the completionhandler is being called.
I don't know how to explain this behavior. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the completion handler will be called on the same thread, so the init method returns and goes into the threadlock, and that locks the completion handler out from being called on that thread.